# How to disable autocomplete textbox for asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

i have gone through all the blogs and solution but still nothing is working for me. anyone please help me on this. I am using asp.net web application. there I want to disable autocomplete textbox functionality.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read the [tour] and [ask] and show a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="idMyTextBox" runat="server" autocomplete="off" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" id="myInputID" name="myInputName" autocomplete="off" >
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but, I have already used all this things autocomplete="off" ,autocomplete="nope", autocomplete="new-password" everything. nothing is working for me.
Is there any other thing which I we can use ?

Comment: I have a master page and content page in content page I am using like this: 
<td align="right" valign="middle">
                        <asp:Label ID="labelUserName" runat="server">User Name</asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" valign="middle">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Width="150px" MaxLength="50" Text="" autocomplete="nope"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>

I have also tried with AutoCompleteType="Disabled" but this is also didn't worked for me

Comment: This code works for me before saving credentials into the browser but after saving this is not working I want restrict those part.
hope you understand my query ?